# Using Python to rename a group of files using an array

Tags: python, arrays, automation

So I have a group of screenshots in a folder on my desktop. I want to rename them using an array of the names I want them to have. So far I am able to get my code to pull the names I want to replace and put them in an array. Then when I try to replace the name using the commented portion of code I loose the files. They disappear and I have no idea where they went. Here is my code:

```
import os       
import sys
import glob
name = ["zero", "It", "Has","Worked"]

print name
print len(name) 
path = "/Users/davidjaimes/Desktop/Test"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
file_list = []

for file in dirs: 
    file_list.append(file)
print file_list


#for item in os.listdir(path):
#    prevName = os.path.join(path, item)
#    newName = name[1]
#   os.rename(prevName, newName)
```

Comment: My guess, They are in your current working directory. The reason is that os.rename, although its name need an absolute path, otherwise it will be relative(it is more like the command "mv").

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, to *open* the files, you needed to append `path` to the name.  In order for the renamed file to stay in the same directory, you must do the same w/ the new name, otherwise they get moved to the current directory (most likely the one you started the program from).

Worse, since you use `name[1]` for the new name *for every file*, you are naming all of the files w/ the same name.

Comment: Exactly. Just as I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks so much! I never knew I had to provide a path for the written files. name[1] is a typo I meant it to be name[i] so that it cycles through the names.

Comment: @DavidJaimes: Note that `i` never changes in the loop you wrote, either.  In fact, it never gets assigned any value at all.

Comment: @ScottHunter yes I see that I have yet to add the loop. I have been Frankensteining this code. I didn't know what was causing my problems so I think I took out the loop to see if that helped. This is my first stack overflow question and I have to say that I am very thankful for your help.